# C++ compiling with MacOS Mojave : fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, macos-mojave

My question closely follows the problem reported here: [Code::Blocks C++ compiling with MacOS Mojave : fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517784/codeblocks-c-compiling-with-macos-mojave-fatal-error-sys-cdefs-h-no-such) (although I am not using CodeBlocks).

I had exactly the same problem and reinstalled gcc and xcode, which fixed the initial error. However, I now have a similar error message with `fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory`

I have tried reinstalling hdf5 and open-mpi similarly and neither have worked. Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Comment: Does your compiler know where to find the mpi header file?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using gcc installed using homebrew -- how would I check this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682860/codeblocks-cant-find-header-files You can try to add the directory of the mpi header.

Comment: I have tried brew install openmpi and mpich, neither work.

Comment: And apologies I am not using CodeBlocks, I will clarfiy the question wording.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher could you please explain how to do this within homebrew? I thought this should be automatic, but it doesn't seem to be working here

Comment: Unfortunately it seems as though mpicxx breaks the code...Is there any way to get around it using g++-8 (my current compiler)

Comment: Still trying, I'll let you know

Comment: Yes works brilliantly, thank you! I also had to remove -fopenmp and -lmpi flags

Comment: Cleaned up the comment in an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMPI comes with a set of wrappers for the compilers:

```
mpicc
mpicxx
```

These will set up all the include paths and libraries to include for the C or the C++ versions of MPI.

If you need to change the underlying compiler (so not use the one by default), you can set:

```
OMPI_CC
OMPI_CXX
```

in the same way as you would set `CC` and `CXX`.